# Hide Field with checkbox

Tags: entities

I'm looking for a way to give an author the possibility to set the field visibility in the node add/edit form. Something like the [Image Hide Module](https://drupal.org/project/image_hide) just for Text Fields with a checkbox behind each text field to select if this field is rendered or not.

Comment: Have you looked into doing something on the node--content-type.tpl.php level? Something like <php if (!empty($content['field_your_field'])): ?> print my other field else don't could do the trick

Comment: Does the content author still need access on the node edit form to the field that is to be hidden? Is this D7? Are you looking for an existing module or are you willing to create your own custom module?

Comment: It's D7. The user still need access. He wan't to decide if the Field content is shown on the site or not. If there is an existing module for that it would be great - creating one own would be my next step.